# Find and Replace a text file in python

Tags: python, replace, find, text-files

Below is the code but the output is wrong where its only outputting the first index values when it loops through. It works when i printed the values of col,rac and mon. I also checked the i values to make sure they are increment the right way.

TEXTFILE:

```
Fav Color   -- *color* 
Fav Car     -- *car*
Number      -- *Money*
```

CODE:

```
with open('carstest.txt', 'r') as file :
    testdata = file.read()

colors = ["RED","GREEN","BLUE"]
car =['Ferrari', 'Mustang','Camero']
Money = ['one','two','three']
i =0
while i <len(colors):
    col = colors[i]
    rac = car[i]
    mon = Money[i]
    testdata = testdata.replace('*color*',  col)
    testdata = testdata.replace('*car*', rac)
    testdata = testdata.replace('*Money*', mon)
    print(testdata)
    i+=1

else:
    print ("DONE")
```

OUTPPUT:

```
Fav Color   -- RED 
Fav Car     -- Ferrari
Number  -- one

Fav Color   -- RED 
Fav Car     -- Ferrari
Number  -- one

Fav Color   -- RED 
Fav Car     -- Ferrari
Number  -- one

DONE
```

Desired Outpput:

```
Fav Color   -- RED 
Fav Car     -- Ferrari
Number  -- one

Fav Color   -- GREEN
Fav Car     -- Mustang
Number  -- two

Fav Color   -- BLUE
Fav Car     -- Camero
Number  -- three

DONE
```

Comment: use `find` in a loop then replace the first instance

Comment: Is your indentation off? with your current formatting you are not even reading the second line in file I suppose as `with` will close the file after it has stopped reading from the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once have done the first round of replacements, the placeholders are no longer there to be replaced.  If you start w/ the original value of `testdata` each iteration, you should be fine.

Comment: Worked Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `while` algorithm. For each additional cycle, you need to reload the original contents of the variable (file contents). In simple terms, you look for a string `*color*` which, unfortunately, no longer exists because `str.replace()` was used. *The `testdata` has therefore changed and the next cycle repeat is no longer relevant.* You have to resolve the algorithm otherwise. For example, at the beginning of the `while` cycle, create a temporary variable:

```
with open('carstest.txt', 'r') as file :
    testdata = file.read()

colors = ['RED','GREEN','BLUE']
car =['Ferrari', 'Mustang','Camero']
Money = ['one','two','three']

i = 0
while i < len(colors):
    s = testdata
    s = s.replace('*color*' , colors[i])
    s = s.replace('*car*'   , car[i])
    s = s.replace('*Money*' , Money[i])
    print(s)
    i += 1
else:
    print ("DONE")
```